# Making maps using the boost::variant library. How to store and display things as the proper type?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to create a map using the boost::variant library, but I can't seem to get any of the data held within the map to print properly.

Code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "boost_1_55_0/boost/any.hpp"
#include "boost_1_55_0/boost/variant.hpp"
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <complex>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::map <string, boost::variant <int, double, bool, string> > myMap;
    myMap.insert(pair<string, int>("PAGE_SIZE",2048));
    myMap.insert(pair<string, boost::variant <int, double,bool, string> > ("PAGE_SIZE2", "hello, this is a string" )); //setup an enum to specify the second value maybe?
    cout << "data page 1: " << myMap["PAGE)SIZE1"] << "\ntype page 1: " << myMap["PAGE_SIZE"].which() << endl;

    cout << "data: " << myMap["PAGE_SIZE2"] << "\ntype: "<< myMap["PAGE_SIZE2"].which()<< endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Ignore all the extra includes, I've been using this file to play around with lots of different ideas. When I compile with g++, I get the following:

```
data page 1: 0
type page 1: 0
data page 2: 1
type page 2: 2
```

I get that the first variable is being stored as an int, and is therefore of type 0, but why is it displaying a value of 0?

Same thing with the second output, except that I don't understand why it's being stored as a bool, is the value a 1 (true)?

All help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: wrt example code: I think it's not a good idea to specify the boost version directory in the #include. Put the boost_1_55_0 into your search path and remove it from the source. IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second is being stored as a `bool` because it's a more basic conversion than to `std::string` (the compiler prefers `const char*` -> `bool` to `const char*` -> `std::string`). As the pointer is non-null it assigns the boolean value true. You can specifically construct a `std::string` here to work around the default conversion.

As for why the data output isn't functioning the only thing I can suspect is that possibly `BOOST_NO_IOSTREAM` is set, causing it to not have the appropriate `operator<<`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using const char* instead of a string and it worked perfectly. The integer output issue was actually a type. I was trying to output a pair that didn't exist (myMap["PAGE)SIZE1"] instead of myMap["PAGE_SIZE"]).